# Can't find "adsutil.vbs" script

Tags: iis, active-directory, windows-server-2022, adsutil.vbs

I'm trying to enable a password web change with IIS, by creating a Virtual Directory,but whene I need to run "adsutil.vbs" I just cant find the script. isn't it supposed to be in C:\intepub\Adminscripts? (can't see the Adminscripts folder either).

Running on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Evaluation

I tried to search online but nothing seems to help.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: If you are referring to the legacy feature IISAPDPWD, you should know it was deprecated as part of IIS 6 and not supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing Managment Tools with Server Manager (IIS Management Scripts and Tools)